# Как из массива отобрать значения, которые больше заданного значения?

Tags: python, numpy

Может, кто-то подскажет?

Дан определенный массив. Пытаюсь отобрать все значения в массиве, которые больше 80. Но выходит ошибка. Что еще можно сделать, чтобы на выходе были все значения больше 80, именно сами значения, а не индексы их расположения?

```
import numpy as np
scores = np.array([[20, 40, 56, 80, 5, 25, 27, 74, 1],
 [98, 67, 100, 8, 56, 34, 82, 100, 7],
 [78, 54, 23, 79, 100, 42, 95, 83],
 [51, 50, 47, 23, 100, 94, 25, 48, 38, 77],
 [90, 87, 41, 89, 52, 5, 17, 28, 99],
 [32, 18, 21, 18, 29, 31, 48, 62, 76, 22],
 [6, 65, 78, 43, 22, 38, 88, 94, 100],
 [77, 28, 39, 41, 81, 45, 54, 98, 12],
 [66, 88, 44, 55, 100, 12, 11],
 [17, 70, 86, 96, 56, 23, 32, 49, 70, 80],
 [20, 24, 76, 50, 29, 40, 3, 2, 5, 11],
 [33, 63, 28, 40, 51, 100, 98, 87, 22, 30],
 [16, 54, 78, 12, 25, 35, 10, 19, 67],
 [100, 88, 24, 33, 47, 56, 62, 34, 77, 53],
 [50, 89, 70, 72, 56, 29, 15, 20]])
scores[scores>=80]
```

Ошибка:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a045ad76049e> in <module>
----> 1 scores[scores>=80]

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'
```

Ответ на выходе, какой хочу получить:

```
array([80, 98, 100, 82, 100,  78,  79, 100,
        95,  83,  100,  94,  77,  90,  87,  89,  99,
        76,  65,  78,  88,  94, 100,  77,  81, 98,   88, 
       100,  70,  86,  96,  70,  80,  76, 63, 100,  98,
        87,  78,   100,  88, 77, 89,  70,
        72])
```

Answer (score 3):

Главная проблема в том, что "подсписки" имеют неодинаковую длину. Для того, чтобы создать двумерную Numpy матрицу все подсписки должны быть одинаковой длины (т.е. число столбцов должно совпадать).

В качестве обходного варианта можно из списка списков создать одномерный вектор и работать с ним:

```
In [76]: x = np.concatenate(scores)

In [77]: x[x>=80]
Out[77]: 
array([ 80,  98, 100,  82, 100, 100,  95,  83, 100,  94,  90,  87,  89,
        99,  88,  94, 100,  81,  98,  88, 100,  86,  96,  80, 100,  98,
        87, 100,  88,  89])
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Comment: @Della333 , если какой-то из ответов вам подошел, его нужно принять.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
scores = [[20, 40, 56, 80, 5, 25, 27, 74, 1],
 [98, 67, 100, 8, 56, 34, 82, 100, 7],
 [78, 54, 23, 79, 100, 42, 95, 83],
 [51, 50, 47, 23, 100, 94, 25, 48, 38, 77],
 [90, 87, 41, 89, 52, 5, 17, 28, 99],
 [32, 18, 21, 18, 29, 31, 48, 62, 76, 22],
 [6, 65, 78, 43, 22, 38, 88, 94, 100],
 [77, 28, 39, 41, 81, 45, 54, 98, 12],
 [66, 88, 44, 55, 100, 12, 11],
 [17, 70, 86, 96, 56, 23, 32, 49, 70, 80],
 [20, 24, 76, 50, 29, 40, 3, 2, 5, 11],
 [33, 63, 28, 40, 51, 100, 98, 87, 22, 30],
 [16, 54, 78, 12, 25, 35, 10, 19, 67],
 [100, 88, 24, 33, 47, 56, 62, 34, 77, 53],
 [50, 89, 70, 72, 56, 29, 15, 20]]

arr = pd.DataFrame(scores).fillna(0).to_numpy()
```

теперь:

```
arr[arr>=80]
```

получим:

```
array([ 80.,  98., 100.,  82., 100., 100.,  95.,  83., 100.,  94.,  90.,
        87.,  89.,  99.,  88.,  94., 100.,  81.,  98.,  88., 100.,  86.,
        96.,  80., 100.,  98.,  87., 100.,  88.,  89.])
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!